# Can't submit gcloud builds

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to submit a build from local workstation and getting non-descriptive error:

```
gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .
Creating temporary tarball archive of 149 file(s) totalling 121.5 MiB before compression.
Uploading tarball of [.] to [gs://***/source/1598211672.63-e76a3db01aa3435885a35cc3b94f0246.tgz]
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

The same `cloudbuild.yaml` run correctly when triggered by git push or github PR comment.
Also, several months ago I was able to submit builds this way.

`gcloud auth list` shows that an active account is the one which definitely has Project Owner role. Furthermore I am able to execute other gcloud commands like storage bucket administration, compute instances management etc.

Comment: Could you please share your cloudbuild.yaml file ? Also could you please confirm that source/1598211672.63-e76a3db01aa3435885a35cc3b94f0246.tgz exist in your Cloud Storage Bucket? What role do you have for your service account? were you able to deploy successfully before?

Comment: I am submitting not from behalf of a service account but a regular user which has a Project Owner role.
`source/1598211672.63-e76a3db01aa3435885a35cc3b94f0246.tgz` exists on a coud storage bucket, it's uploaded by this `gcloud builds submit ...` command (note dot at the end).
I've been able to deploy successful before, months ago. And every day this cloudbuild.yam is successfully deployed by a vcs push trigger. The problem is just with manual cli submit.

I've put cloudbuild.yaml into edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is working as intended and it's documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_user-defined_substitutions):

> By default, the build returns an error if there's a missing
> substitution variable or a missing substitution. However, you can set
> the ALLOW_LOOSE option to skip this check.

also when you invoke your build with a trigger:

> If your build is invoked by a trigger, the ALLOW_LOOSE option is set
> by default. In this case, your build will not return an error if there
> is a missing substitution variable or a missing substitution. You
> cannot override the ALLOW_LOOSE option for builds invoked by triggers.

Comment: I intuitively felt that if substitution has a default value like in my case than there won't be an error if ALLOW_LOOSE isn't set. Apparently, it's vice-versa, default value is used only if ALLOW_LOOSE is set.

Answer (score 0):

I've added

```
options:
  substitution_option: 'ALLOW_LOOSE'
```

to cloudbuild.yaml, and build submits now.
For some reason, if cloudbuild.yaml has defined substitutions like:

```
substitutions:
  _SLACK_MESSAGE_TEMPLATE: 'backend build succeeded"
```

cli cloudbuild submit returns an error, even if I provide `_SLACK_MESSAGE_TEMPLATE` via `--substitutions`.